# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile after upgrading Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

We recently upgraded the version of struts in our website from 2.1.8.1 to 2.3.4.  Immediately after upgrading we noticed the following exception after the first post back to the server.  Any help in determining the issue or how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated.  We've been scratching our head for days.  The thing that makes this really bad is when the site is deployed to websphere once this exception is thrown the site stops working completely until you restart the jvm.  In tom cat the below exception is thrown but the site continues to work.

```
2013-09-17 15:09:18,919 [WebContainer : 0] ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager - Caught exception while loading file java/lang/Object-validation.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:383)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:271)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:363)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:342)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:342)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:125)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:120)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:222)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:432)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1079)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:999)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
```

Comment: Please include the exact list of libraries you're deploying, or your pom.xml

Comment: `java/lang/Object-validation.xml` ??!

Comment: Seems tomcat is a hard to die web server.

Comment: Looks like there was a bug in struts 2.3.4 library and which was resolved in 2.3.7 version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311041&version=12323448 

[WW-3850] - NullPointerException loading xwork validator since 2.3.4

I was incorrect when I said we upgraded to 2.3.8.  I thought we did bbut apparently in our working late I missed that we didn't actually deploy that upgrade.  Anyway, problem solved by upgrading to struts2 2.3.8 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a bug in struts 2.3.4 library and which was resolved in 2.3.7 version. issues.apache.org/jira/secure/…[WW-3850] - NullPointerException loading xwork validator since 2.3.4 I was incorrect when I said we upgraded to 2.3.8. I thought we did bbut apparently in our working late I missed that we didn't actually deploy that upgrade. Anyway, problem solved by upgrading to struts2 2.3.8 or higher. –